Android OS 13 - Grant MediaProjection permission using Accessibility service
I'm working on a app which is a private app i.e. it won't be published on the Google Play Store.
I'm using Android OS 13 device. My app have a screen casting functionality. To use this functionality, app needs a Media Projection permission. And whenever a screen casting is initiated, a device propmt the permission and device-user needs to grant it to start the casting. Once permission granted, screen cast works fine.
My app does have the Accessibilty permission.
So is it possible to auto-grant the media projection permission using Accessibility? If yes, then it will be helpful if you provide some insights about how this can be achieved.
I tried to listen the Accessibility events & try to get the details of the view displayed on the Screen when the permission dialog is displayed. I got the class name as AlertDialog and the list of texts displayed on the AlertDialog.
But I'm not able to figure out how I can get the View of the particular buttons of AlertDialog. If I get the view details, then I can perform the click event injection on that button view.
Thank you,
Neo

No, Accessibility services cannot auto-grant media projection permission as it requires explicit user consent through system dialogs for security reasons of the device.

Yes @Maveňツ, you are right, Accessibility service can not be used to auto-grant the media projection permission. However, through the Accessibility service, I got the details (Media Projection permission Alert dialog text) of the permission dialog like texts appear on a dialog. Is there a way to use this information i.e. Text to find out the button component? If yes, then I can inject the click event.
